# Getting "NaN" in Neural Style Transfer code

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

long ago i did the Deep Learning specialization on Coursera and i rewrite the NST notebook's code so it will run on Spyder. The code did run well and i haven't touch it for a year. Now i tried to run it again and i get "NaN" in the cost function and the generated picture is black. I tried to see the values of the variables from the Variables Explorer and it seems fine. Someone has an idea why it happens? i didn't change the code at all and the only thing i did since last year is installing packages.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you remember on which version of tensorflow it was running then? Try downgrading tensorflow version to previously used and see if the problem is still occurring.

Comment: I don't remember which version i had back then, but it was 1.X and now i have 1.14 so i doubt if that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

either your model's weight too large or the learning rate is too large so it diverges, now, make sure to tune the learning rate (make it smaller than it's now) or use grad/weights clipping

Comment: I reduced the learning rate and it still gives me "NaN". The weird thing is that last year i didn't have this problem and now i have, even though i didn't change the code and the file with the weights.

Comment: try to access the course material and run it on Coursera's platform

Comment: I can't access it anymore but i ran now the same notebook from Coursera on Jupyter notebook and it does the same problem. Is it possible that the code is good and the problem is the library?